# How does 分 and として work in this sentence?

Tags: particles

女性との行為に価値を認めていない**分**、ハードルも低いという事なのだろうが、エアリエル**として**は堪らない。

Does it works as "Due to" or "Because of"? I have been encountering this kanji used in the same manner and I tried searching about it but it doesn't seem to be considered as a particle so I had no luck.

として on the underhand does not make sense either. Was it "It's unbearable as Ariel"? or was it actually と＋して or "Doing it to Ariel"?

Comment: As for the 分: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36659/9831

Comment: ... aand the ～としては means "for ~", "from ~'s viewpoint", "as far as ~ is concerned" "as for~" (≂にとっては、～にしてみれば) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42783/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 女性との行為に価値を認めていない**分**、

I think it is rather close to "Because of", but "to the degree that 女性との行為に価値を認めていない" is better.

**EDIT**: "to the extent that ...." by A.Ellett is better than my "to the degree that ...." for the meaning of 分.

英語には余り自信がないので日本語で回答すると、「認めていない分」は、「認めていないだけ」あるいは「認めていないだけ**に**」に近いと思います。 ２つの中では、「認めていないだけ**に**」の方が「悔しい ≒ 堪｛たま｝らない」気持ちが表現できているので良いと思います。

> エアリエル**として**は堪らない。

It is "It's unbearable as Ariel"

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! Your English is fine though, probably even better than mine.

Comment: I was thinking that 分 in this context means something like "to the extent that ...."

Comment: I see. So I roughly got it right. Thanks a lot!