# Can anyone give me some more examples/resources about 分 used in a conditional(?) sense

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

I'm translating a song and came across this line in bold:

> よりにもよって 性質が悪い/**はしゃいだ分 虚しくなるんだな**/真夜中にふと目が覚めて それから/君がいないことに気づく

I am planning to translate it in this format

> If you はしゃぐ, you'll 虚しくなる。

or

> Because if you はしゃぐ, you will 虚しくなる。

Are either of these correct? This is my first time seeing 分 used in this way. I've looked up some examples like:

> 不足した分は私が払っておこう

The dictionary translated this as, "I will make up the rest."  But does this literally translate to "If it is not enough, I will pay the rest?"

> 先生にほめられた分だけ勉強するようになった

The dictionary translated this as, "He has come to work (all the) harder after being praised by the teacher." I don't really understand how to literally translate this though.

> 毎日見ている分、なじみがある

And then I also saw this ~分には format

> そんなこと気にしていた分には何も出来なくなってしまう

The dictionary translated this as, "If you worry about things like that, you won't be able to do anything at all."

> ただ見る分には差し支えないでしょう

> 見てる分にはいいけれど

> 見てる分にはかわいいけど

I got the examples from these sources:

- 分 in [プログレッシブ和英辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%88%86/#je-67507)
- [clause ending 分](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61583/9831)
- [The meaning of "ぶん" in "見ているぶんには..."](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13653/9831)

Anyway, I'm still having trouble understanding this construction (or possibly these constructions) with 分 even with these examples. If anyone can show me some more examples or resources on this topic I'd be very thankful

Comment: Seriously? The question said "I got the examples from these sources" "I'm still having trouble understanding". And then you guys point to the exact same source stating "This question already has an answer here"? Come on...

Comment: Regarding the 分 in はしゃいだ分 虚しくなるんだな, the 1st paragraph of this answer here might be of help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61588/9831 `I would say the sense of this 分 usage is to indicate a kind of "proportional increase" - the 分 indicates that whatever comes after it is increasing in proportion to what comes before it.`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you already have great examples. The lyric is probably expressing the emotional emptiness which is the result of partying and having fun. However such expression tends to include irony, so you may want to consider that.

Long answer:

> Can anyone give me some more examples/resources about 分 used in a conditional(?) sense

I'll give you one that may help digest the fundamental concept of 分: **食べた分だけ太る**

分 can mean "share", as in "that's my share".
Imagine a pizza or pie, and split it into two.

The left side is your share. Your 分.

The right side is mine. My 分.

No, I'm not saying Japanese people slice pizza into two halves. This is just a simplified example.

While calorie intake may not be the sole factor to our weight, let's say **the more (share of) pizza I eat, the more weight I gain.** This exactly is what I meant by **食べた分だけ太る**

Back to your example. **先生にほめられた分だけ勉強する** can be interpreted as **the more (share of) ほめる I receive from teacher, the more I 勉強する**, or "the more my teacher praised me, I studied".

With the above logic, you may begin to understand that the lyric was indeed articulating the cause-and-effect relationship between **はしゃいだ分** and **虚しくなる**.

Next, note that the lyric dropped **だけ**. だけ would basically mean "only" in other use cases. While tempting to translate as "the amount of pizza I eat is the **only** weight I gain" or "I **only** study when my teacher praises me", that wouldn't be correct when used in these expressions. Instead, the **だけ** makes the cause and effect to sound **relatively** linked. Although unsure weather the relationship is proportional, exponential, etc, nevertheless **the more I X, the more I Y**. Think of a mathematical function.

Dropping the **だけ** tends to change this. Your example **毎日見ている分、なじみがある**, omits **だけ** like the lyrics. Here the relationship between the cause (毎日見ている) and effect (なじみがある) is absolute. It's simply stating that "because of the **cause** there is the **effect**" whereas the pizza and teacher example with だけ would be "the **more** cause the **more** effect".